# How to handle React Native error message: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<' ..in tryCallOne ..in <unknown>

Tags: spring-boot, expo, react-native-ios

I'm trying to learn how to connect a React Native app (currently also using expo) with a Spring Boot server.

I saw similar questions about this error message online with the response that it's an issue caused by an error in the URL. Is that the case? Another response I saw was that the " Ünrecognized token'<' " meant that the response was coming back in html and not JSON, however, in testing a GET request to my API in Postman I got back JSON: [{"id":1,"organizer":"OrganizerTest1","location":"LocationTest1"}, ...]

For my app '**exp://172.20.10.6:19000**' is the app port (At least,I believe that's what it is).

But I'm getting the JSON Parse Error back.

> "JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'
>   - node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:37:14 in tryCallOne
>   - node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:123:25 in 
>   - ... 8 more stack frames from framework internals"

```
class GamesCollection  extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      error: false,
      games: [],
    }
  }


  componentDidMount = async () => {
  try {
    let response = await fetch('http://172.20.10.6:19000/games',{
            headers:{
                Accept:'application/json',
                'Content-Type':'application/json',
            }
        })
    let games = await response.json()
    this.setState({loading: false, games})
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    this.setState({loading: false, error: true})
  }
}


server in Java  Spring Boot:

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")


public class GameController {
    private final GameRepository repository;

    GameController(GameRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    //Aggregate root

    @GetMapping("/games")
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "")

    public List<Game> all() {
                return repository.findAll();
    }
```

Comment: Try constructing headers with new Headers() constructor.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code. Did you enable CORS on your SpringBoot-Server?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to specify JSON as the response type. E.g.:

`@GetMapping(value = "/games", produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")`

Also, make sure that you're hitting the right server address. `172.20.10.6:19000` might not be the correct host & port combination. Usually spring boot, by default, starts the server on port `8080`.

Comment: thank you! you're right, both of these fixed the issue.